# Read PDF from shared folder

Tags: file, pdf, grails, groovy

I have this Grails project where I need to read file(s) from a path I get from an endpoint.

Apparently chrome blocks "Not allowed to load local resource" so I cannot just use a href to read my pdf file in my browser. I need to show my pdf in and a new browser window but nothing helps.

```
    def link = "path"
    def file = new File(link)


    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=gdoc.pdf")
    response.outputStream << file.newInputStream()
```

This is what I've got but can't seem to read my file, I always end up getting "No such file or directory" although I can access it from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you're trying to implement a "proxy" between the user and the pdf creating a new Grails controller.

As the error message is "No such file or directory" I suspect this error came in the server when you try to do `File = new File("path")` ... so are you sure in the server there is a subfolder called "path" where the grails application is running ?

Comment: path is just a placeholder for my real path which I'm not going post on stackoverflow.

Comment: as per the answer, it appears new File is unable to open what ever the real path being provided to it - this is really something server operator can resolve - the starting point is to enable debug i.e. println "trying to open link $link" then logging onto server to work out. 1. does this file / path exist - 2. Is this file / path accessible by the user running your web application. It is likely 2 could be causing permission issues resulting in similar outcome.

Comment: following @Vahid advise I suggest to you put a trace with the absolutePath of file
  `println file.absolutePath`

Answer (score 0):

Dependency-inject the `ResourceLoader` bean and use this to access the PDF, e.g.

```
import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader

class MyService implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    InputStream getPdfContent() {
        Resource pdf = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:path/toPdf.p12")
        pdf.inputStream
    }
}
```